# How to find cell width from StaggeredGridLayoutManager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter, staggered-gridview, staggeredgridlayout

I have a `StaggeredGrid` in a `RecyclerView` and I am trying to dynamically set the image height in the `onBindViewHolder`. I thought the `StaggeredGrid` was supposed to handle all this automatically, so I set `android:layout_width="match_parent` and `android:scaleType="fitStart` on the `ImageView`, but there is lots of gaps around the image.

Since the `StaggeredGrid` isn't living up to it, I'm trying to help it a bit by defining the image height dynamically in the `onBindViewHolder`. I have the width and height of the image ahead of time, but the cell width of the grid isn't available. I tried `holder.cardView.getLayoutParams().width` and `getMeasuredWidth()`, but they both return zero or small numbers. I know there are other places the cell width would be available, but I really need it in the `onBindViewHolder` event so I can set and adjust the image.

Any ideas on how to achieve this by leveraging the `StaggeredGrid`? Any advice or experience is appreciated!

In my activity is this:

```
mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

In my adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MyModel item = mData.get(position);

    int imageWidth = item.getFeatured_image().getWidth();
    int imageHeight = item.getFeatured_image().getHeight();
    int cellWidth = 540; // <==== how to find dynamically??!!

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams imageLayoutParams = holder.thumbnailImageView.getLayoutParams();
    imageLayoutParams.width = cellWidth;
    imageLayoutParams.height = imageHeight * cellWidth / imageWidth;
    holder.thumbnailImageView.setLayoutParams(imageLayoutParams);

    MediaHelper.displayImage(item, holder.thumbnailImageView);
}
```

In my layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/row_my_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_my_thumbnail_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_my_title_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#CCFFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I also tried to add this which does give me the cell width, but the `onGlobalLayout` event gets triggered way after the image is set and adjusted in the `onBindViewHolder` event so it's too late.

```
@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.row_my_post, parent, false);

    final MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                int viewWidth = view.getWidth();
                int viewHeight = view.getHeight();
            }
        });
    }

    return viewHolder;
}
```

Here is the gaps which are random due to the various image sizes. What I would like is for ALL images to be the width of the cell and let the height of the image and cell adjust dynamically:

[image]

Comment: Any chance at all you could add a screenshot of this gap so that it would be obvious that the gap is not due to inherent padding inside the cardview and is actually a bigger gap than that?

Comment: Ok thank you. Next question: The gap you're referring to is for the image itself or for the spacing between the cards?

Comment: Gaps to the right of the image. See "7 ways to use cashew milk", there's a gap to the right because it couldn't fill up the width.

Comment: Btw, using my hard coded `540` cell width number in my `onBindViewHolder` sample above, all the image width fill up the card nicely. I just can't find the actual cell width dynamically there instead of hard coding it (540 happens to be the cell width of this device/simulator... I guess it's half the resolution size because of my `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` set to 2 columns).

Comment: use this param in your ImageView---> android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: @AmarbirSingh WOW that simple param worked!! Pls add as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: @TruMan1  I have posted this please upvote my answer!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try This:- add this in your ImageView--> android:adjustViewBounds="true"

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
 xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/row_my_card"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_margin="5dp"
 card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/row_my_thumbnail_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_my_title_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#CCFFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="5dp" />
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of getting the view height and width from `onCreateViewHolder` get it from `onBindViewHolder` as below:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) 
{
    holder.itemView.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            MyModel item = mData.get(position);
            int imageWidth = item.getFeatured_image().getWidth();
            int imageHeight = item.getFeatured_image().getHeight();
            int cellWidth = 540; // <==== how to find dynamically??!!

            cellWidth = holder.itemView.getWidth();// this will give you width dynamically

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams imageLayoutParams = holder.thumbnailImageView.getLayoutParams();
            imageLayoutParams.width = cellWidth;
            imageLayoutParams.height = imageHeight * cellWidth / imageWidth;
            holder.thumbnailImageView.setLayoutParams(imageLayoutParams);
            MediaHelper.displayImage(item, holder.thumbnailImageView);
        }
    });
}
```

I hope this will help you!!

Comment: This is what I tried before but the width returns 0 because it is not rendered yet.

Comment: it is rendered when u post to get the width. it works.

Comment: You're right it does work! I didn't notice the post/runnable method. I went with the layout solution since it is simple and more natural to the layout. Thx for sharing this as I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: It's 2022. I tried many answers. but none of them was accurate. This one just did the job as expected

Answer (score 0):

The cell's width can be found at activity/fragment level and passed to the adapter before rendering time. Use something like this:

```
this.staggeredGridLayoutManager.getWidth() / this.staggeredGridLayoutManager.getSpanCount()
```

With this approach, you will be able to compute the cell's height before any rendering and avoid that initial flick introduced by post run approach.
Also, the image's aspect ratio will be preserved and you can reserve the required space before image load.

Be also aware that if any margins/paddings are present you should include them into previous calculation. Something like:

```
(this.staggeredGridLayoutManager.getWidth() - marginsAndOrPaddings) / this.staggeredGridLayoutManager.getSpanCount()
```

**Update:**
Starting with support packages 23.2.0, and at this point of lifecycle, *this.staggeredGridLayoutManager.getWidth()* returns 0. The total width can be achieved with ***this.recyclerView.getWidth()***